# UITextView textViewShouldEndEditing / textViewDidEndEditing not called

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

I have a screen with several `UITextField`s and `UITextView`s.

Even though the "official" method to end the editing of a `UITextField` is to Touch the Done key on the keyboard, and the "official" method for a `UITextView` is to touch an external Done button - and I support both - I can't prevent the user from switching to another text field or text view by simply touching that other control.

This works fine if the current control being edited is a `UITextField`. When the user touches the second control, `TextFieldDidEndEditing:` is called for the current text field and I can handle the data in that field.

However, if the current control is a `UITextView`, when the user touches another control neither `textViewShouldEndEditing` nor `textViewDidEndEditing` are called. The only way to cause them to be called is to do an explicit `ResignFirstResponder` when the second control is touched, but this causes the keyboard to be dismissed, so the new touch is effectively ignored (the user has to touch the new field again to resume editing).

Is there a way to cause a `UITextView` to behave like a `UITextField` when another control is being touched?

Comment: works for me. Are you sure you set the delegate of the textView? Okay, if it works when you manually use resignFirstResponder you probably have.

Answer (score 0):

in the textViewShouldEndEditing and textViewDidEndEditing methods put an if-else clause.

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
   if (textView = (your text view property)
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```